# get twitter count

Tags: php, twitter

I need PHP code for user twitter count

Thanks

Comment: read the manual for friends api http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554707/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-friends%C2%A0ids

Comment: Please be more specific: are you trying to count user's followers? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `if( $username == 'Jack Dorsey' ) { echo 'You have 1 Twitter.' } else { echo 'You have 0 Twitters.' }`

Comment: `<?php echo 'You have over nine thousand Twitters.'; ?>`

Comment: <?php echo 'I am lazy, can you do my job for me?'; ?>

Comment: sorry, but I am new to twitter, don't know about it's apiwiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API website from Twitter: http://dev.twitter.com/.

Tutorials with php: http://www.newwebplatform.com/tips-and-tutorials/Twitter#PHP.